# subversion and tortoise conflict

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I can't do checkout of my repository which is located on my svn-server.
Subversion server version is 1.8 and tortoise too.
There's no problem on other computers. It works ok. Only for one lets say 192.168.1.5
On this computer when I use browser:

```
 http://svn-server/my_repo
```

theres no problem. So it's not DNS issue.

Tortoise error:

```
Subversion reported an error:
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn-server/my_repo'
Server sent unexpected return value (503 Service Unavailable) in response to
OPTIONS request for http://svn-server/my_repo
```

Tortoise `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe log http://svn-server/my_repo` yielded this exception:

```
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on '/my_repository' failed: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Apache error log:

```
[error] [client 192.168.1.5] access to /my_repo failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler.
```

Apache subversion config:

```
<Location /my_repo>
DAV svn
SVNPath /srv/svn/repos/ict
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "Subversion My_Repo"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL ldap://my_ldap/dc=domain,dc=com?cn?sub
Allow from 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
Require ldap-attribute title=repo
</Location>
```

Of course ldap user has this attribute and computer is in ip range.

It works when I try on different computer in network, even with older version 1.7 of tortoise. Why it doens't work only for this specific one and what is exactly apache error tells me?

Comment: maybe that computer isn't joined to the domain?

Comment: TortoiseSVN ships with command-line tools as well. Do the command-line tools (e.g. `svn log {url}`) work?

Comment: I don't see any commandline tool in Tortoise and command "svn" is not recognized by windows comandline

Comment: @Ben I have the same Problem as OP. On my machine the command svn.exe log {url} yields the same error (`svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on '/svn' failed: 503 Service Unavailable`)

Comment: @s1c Did you ever come around to solve this?

Comment: @Ben I solved it. See answer, no more investigation required.

Answer (score 0):

You have Network problems, most likely a proxy or something.

Open the settings of TortoiseSVN and navigate to "Network" double check that you have the same proxy configuration as on your browser.

I found this after searching for the error code "svn: E175002".